# Как задать расстояние между полями формы?

Tags: html, css

Как можно задать расстояние между полями формы? Нужно сделать отступ сверху и слева в полях ввода и убрать рамки.

[Сodepen](https://codepen.io/camobap6/pen/RwrQBam)

```css
.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 430px;
  height: 330px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.form__sumbit-button {
  display: flex;
  margin: 193px auto 0;
  width: 358px;
  height: 50.15px;
  background: #000000;
  align-items: center;
}

.form__save {
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
}

.profile__buttonClose {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  align-self: flex-end;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" id="form">
  <button class="profile__buttonClose"></button>
  <label>
    имя
    <input type="text" name="nameInput"/>
  </label>
  <label>
    должность
    <input type="text" name="jobInput"/>
  </label>
  <button class="form__sumbit-button" type="submit">
    <h3 class="form__save">Сохранить</h3>
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.form input[type="text"]{
border:0;
margin-left:10px;
margin-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: спасибо вроде оно